# This circuit is two parallel resistances of 10Ω. Convince me otherwise

Tags: resistors, thevenin, linear

I'm trying to find the Thévenin equivalent resistance of a circuit - one that resembles a Wheatstone bridge, but is not at balance. The load in question is where the galvanometer would appear.

Anyway, I have disconnected the load, removed the (ideal) sources, and redrawn the circuit as below.

To me, the resistance seen by the load on AB is two series combinations, both of which evaluate to 10, in parallel - an equivalent resistance of 5Ω.

This is apparently incorrect. My textbook calculates the Thévenin resistances as:

$$ R_L = \frac{3 \times 7}{3+7} + \frac{4 \times 6}{4+6} = 2.1 + 2.4 = 4.5Ω $$

Can someone please explain?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2cWVK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

TIA

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you calculated 10 Ω for the series combinations. Maybe then we can help you.

Comment: So you say 3 Ohm + 7 Ohm in series as well as 4 Ohm and 6 Ohm in series?

Comment: Yes. Why is this incorrect?

Comment: Because 3 Ω and 7 Ω are in parallel as are the 4 Ω and 6 Ω.

Comment: The 3+7 series may not both start and end at point A. And the 4+6 series cannot both start and end in point B.

Comment: Many thanks to whoever downvoted me for a simple beginner's error!

Comment: You simply have "series" and "parallel" completely swapped throughout your question.

Comment: The ratio of 3/7 and 7/13 cannot be equal, because there are no common denominator factors. Thus there is current thru that crosstie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this is what you drew

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2cWVK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let me slightly redraw this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIJygl.png)</sup>

it is clear there is two series connected parallel branches.

( 3||7 ) + ( 4 || 6 )  which equates to 4.5R

Comment: This is a perfect explanation. It won't let me accept the answer for another 7 minutes, but be assured I will. Thank you for your help!